# How to check if digit appears 3 or more times in a long

Tags: java, long-integer

I want to validate a long number. It must be a 12-digit. If it contains a 0, or any digit appears 3 times or more, the number is invalid. I have written this code, how can I check if any digit appears 3 times or more?

```
public boolean Valid(Long number) {
       
        String id = Long.toString(number);
        if(id.length() != 12)
            return false;
        if(String.valueOf(id).contains("0"))
            return false;

        //check if any digit appears 3 times or more        
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: take a look at `String`'s `indexOf` method (the overloaded one with 2 parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit::** Just realised I misunderstood the requirement here, as the goal is to account for any digit occurring three or more times. Here's a solution with that in mind, and some updated tests:

```
@Test
public void validationTest() {
    //12 chars, no digit repeated more than twice
    assertTrue(isValid(123456123456L));
    //Digit occurs three times
    assertFalse(isValid(123356123456L));
    //Digit occurs four times
    assertFalse(isValid(123336123456L));
    //Less than 12 length
    assertFalse(isValid(12L));
    //More than 12 length
    assertFalse(isValid(1234561234567L));
    //Contains 0
    assertFalse(isValid(103456123456L));
}

static boolean isValid(long in) {
    final String str = String.valueOf(in);

    if(str.length() != 12)
        return false;

    if(str.contains("0"))
        return false;

    return str.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .values().stream()
            .noneMatch(count -> count >= 3);
}
```

Here's another method that's a bit more low level, and doesn't use streams. Some people may find it more readable:

```
static boolean isValid(long in) {
    final String str = String.valueOf(in);

    if(str.length() != 12)
        return false;

    final int[] digits = new int[10];
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        final int idx = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        if(idx == 0 || ++digits[idx] >= 3)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

One more too, as I'm having some fun with this:

```
static boolean isValid(long in) {
    if((int)(Math.log10(in)+1) != 12)
        return false;

    final Map<Long, Long> map = LongStream.range(0,12)
            .map(i -> (in/(long)Math.pow(10,i))%10)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    return !map.containsKey(0L) && map.values().stream().noneMatch(count -> count >= 3);
}
```

Comment: It always advised to not try this `.mapToObj(c -> (char)c)` on a string. For this problen, it might be fine as it handles only `0-9` but for a general string, this can result in incorrect output due to incorrect conversion of code points to chars

Comment: That's good general advice, thanks. This could just as easily use `boxed()` as well, as it's only being used as a key that's discarded.

Answer (score 2):

### groupby digit and check by count

```java
//return false if any digit appears 3 times or more
return id.chars().boxed()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) // group by digit and get count
  .values().stream().noneMatch(count -> count >= 3); // filter by count >= 3
```

Based on the above check, the code can be written

```java
  return id.length() == 12 
    && !id.contains("0") 
    && id.chars().boxed()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) // group by digit and get count
      .values().stream().noneMatch(count -> count >= 3);
```

### Disclaimer

Though streams are expressive, it will be difficult to debug when used on complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

This detects the occurrence of any digit (input your string and 3) efficiently.

```
static class IntPtr {
        int value;
}

static boolean hasRepetition(String s, int amount) {
        HashMap<Character, IntPtr> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            IntPtr ip = map.computeIfAbsent(s.charAt(i), k -> new IntPtr());
            ip.value++;
            if(ip.value >= amount) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just scan digits and count them:

```
public static boolean Valid(long number) {
  if (number < 1_000_000_000_000L || number >= 10_000_000_000_000L)
    return false;

  int[] digits = new int[10];

  for (long data = number; data != 0; data /= 10) {
    int digit = (int) (data % 10); 

    if (0 == digit)
      return false;   
    if (++digits[digit] >= 3)
      return false;
  } 

  return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to store the occurrence of each digit and then check if any digits occurs more than 3 times then you can return false.

Here is the **Code**:

```
 public class Main {
        public static boolean Valid(Long number) {
            int arr[]=new int[11];
            String id = Long.toString(number);
            if(id.length() != 12)return false;
            if(String.valueOf(id).contains("0"))
                return false;
            for(int i=0;i<id.length();i++){
                int temps =0;
                temps = id.charAt(i)-48;
                arr[temps]++;
            }
    
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                if(arr[i]>=3)return false;
            }
    
            return true;
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println(Valid(103456789125L));  //false zero
            System.out.println(Valid(111456789125L)); //false 3
            System.out.println(Valid(125L)); //false less than 12 digits
            System.out.println(Valid(123456789123L)); //true 12 digits no zeros and not 3 digits repeted.
    
        }
    }
```

**Output:**
false
false
false
true